SQL insert into primary table and its foreign table
I have more or less a simple key-value database that maps a path to a Debian package name. To normalize the database and save disk space, the package names are put into a packages table and referred to them via an ID:
CREATE TABLE packages (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  package text NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE path_package (
  path TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  package_id integer NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (package_id) REFERENCES packages(id)
);

Adding a new key-value pair needs two to three SQL statements in the most naive implementation:
import sqlite3

class Path2Package(collections.abc.Mapping[str, str]):
    def __init__(self, database: str) -> None:
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(database)

    def __setitem__(self, path: str, package: str) -> None:
        found = self.connection.execute(
            "SELECT id from packages WHERE package = ?", (package,)
        ).fetchone()
        if found is None:
            found = self.connection.execute(
                "INSERT INTO packages (package) VALUES(?) RETURNING id", (package,)
            ).fetchone()
            assert found is not None
        package_id = found[0]

        self.connection.execute(
            "INSERT INTO path_package VALUES(?, ?) "
            "ON CONFLICT(path) DO UPDATE SET package_id=excluded.package_id",
            (path, package_id),
        )

Since this table can have million of entries, creating those entries is performance relevant. I want to keep the amount of Python code small since Python is much slower than the sqlite3 module code (written in C?). Is there a way to combine those SQL statements into one so that can be used with connection.executemany?
Context: I want a fast implementation that also works on low memory systems and consume less on-disk space. This is to fix apport-retrace needs more than 1.5 GB memory (when using sandbox). Different implementations and benchmark results can be found on https://github.com/bdrung/apport/blob/benchmark-databases/Benchmark.md.

I don't think there's really anything simpler than this. You could do INSERT INTO path_package SELECT ... FROM packages ... and check if this inserted anything. But then you'll still need two queries to insert into packages and path_packages when the package isn't found.

There's no way to insert into two tables at once.


Since this table can have million of entries, creating those entries is performance relevant.

The biggest performance boost would be to insert many paths with one statement.
You could change your method to accept a package name and an array of paths. For example, if a package had 10 paths, you would do one insert like so.
INSERT INTO path_package(package_id, path) VALUES
  (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?),(?, ?), (?, ?)

This also reduces the number of times you need to select or insert the package.
You can construct this by hand, but it's better to use a SQL Builder such as SQLAlchemy.
